# Facebook debugger grabs the right thumbnails, but FB doesn't

Tags: facebook, wordpress, share

When I test my post page on [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.moroccoenglish.com/vocabulary-works-make-or-do/) I get no errors and no warnings, and it grabs the right thumbnail besides the default one.

That's the result I want when I would share my post on facebook, but it doesn't happen.
How can fix this strange annoying problem?

This is an example link page related to my issue:
http://www.moroccoenglish.com/vocabulary-works-make-or-do/

Comment: Try to use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-facebook-open-graph-protocol/ 
It seems facebook has some issues with wordpress

Comment: arleady tried many pligins ...and codes ... I donno what do I miss!

Comment: I actually don't really know how to help you, but have you tried to use only one image? instead of declaring those 3?

Comment: I declared for one default image incase there is no image on the shared image ..FB would grabe it ... but the posts I share include images .... they should be grabed first .... but FB just focus on the right side bar images which are larger .... should I include large images in my pages   .... ??? strange !

Comment: I have got an observation about this issue : When I resize up my post thumbnail dimensions to over 250 px x 250px ... it shows up among the images grabed by FB ...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. After changing the og:image to a bigger one, everything solved. I think og:image should be bigger than 250 x250. Also noticed you have declared og:image two times with two different images.